# How to increment column in R data frame by one?

Tags: r

So I have data like this

```
            Date    DJIA Time
1     1/1/96 5117.12    1
2     1/2/96 5177.45    2
3     1/3/96 5194.07    3
4     1/4/96 5173.84    4
5     1/5/96 5181.43    5
6     1/8/96 5197.68    6
```

I want to decrement the values in the Time column by 1 and remove the first row.

I've achieved both of these steps separately-

```
data[-1,]
```

removes the first row, while

```
data$Time - 1
```

decrements, but returns me the decremented columns.

How do I make it so that I get something like this

```
        Date    DJIA Time
1     1/2/96 5177.45    1
2     1/3/96 5194.07    2
3     1/4/96 5173.84    3
4     1/5/96 5181.43    4
5     1/8/96 5197.68    5
```

?

I've also tried

```
data[-1,]$Time - 1
```

but this again returns me only the time vector decremented by 1, as opposed to changing the entire data frame.

Comment: So what's wrong with `data <- data[-1,]; data$Time <- data$Time -1`?

Answer (score 4):

This you got right:

```
data[-1,]
data$Time - 1
```

But, as you said, it returns a new data frame; it doesn't change what you already have. So you just need to assign the result back to `data`:

```
data <- data[-1,]
data$Time <- data$Time - 1
```

To better understand, you can do `newData <- data[-1,]` to *create a new* data frame without the first row. If you want to transform your original data frame, you need to re-assign it `data <- ...`. Same goes for columns or rows, you need to do `data$column <- ...`.

Comment: but what I get back is a vector, rather than the data frame?

Comment: ohhh didn't see hte assign back to the column part